# Pass value between asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net with c# in backcode. On my first page, I have a hyperlink with 
`NavigateUrl ="Order.aspx?productId = " + ProductID` . I want to transfer `ProductID` in `Order.aspx` file.
So, how to get it in target file :`Order.aspx`.

I used a lable to display in Order.aspx file

`string productId = Request.QueryString["productId"];`

`lblTest.Test = productId`

But `lblTest` didn't display anything

Thanks.

Comment: Please rephrase your question

Answer (score 4):

You would read the QueryString values of the Request object.

```
string productId = Request.QueryString["productId"];
```

You'd have to parse it into an integer if that is what it is.

```
NavigateUrl ="Order.aspx?productId = " + ProductID
```

You might also want to get rid of the spaces in your URL.

Comment: Like I said, change your URL. The spaces in `proudctId = ` might cause you problems. Debug the page and see what `Request.QueryString["productId"]` is returning.

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = Request.QueryString["productId"];
```

Its advisable that you verify whether Request.QueryString["productId"] is really present.

Answer (score 0):

Use the request collection

```
string productId = Request["productId"];
```

Be careful what you do with this variable. E.g. don't store it directly in a database or append it to an inline query.

Comment: Incorrect. See here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETParamsCollectionVsQueryStringFormsVsRequestindexAndDoubleDecoding.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If ProductID is a server-side variable, use this:
NavigateUrl = "Order.apx?productId = "<% =ProductID %>

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
="Order.aspx?productId = " + ProductID;
```

Remove the space 
My code:

```
="Order.aspx?productId=" + ProductID;
```